# How to remove duplicate values on the same row using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, deduplication

I want to remove duplicated columns/fields on the same row only. I tried, but I ended up with a long code with nest loops, conditions and arrays that doesn't work correctly.

- input data:

  ```
  1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 1
  1 2 1 3
  4 4 3 2
  3 3 3 2
  1 1 1 1
  5 2 2 7
  ```
- desired output:

  ```
  1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 
  1 2 3
  4 3 2
  3 2
  1
  5 2 7
  ```

Comment: You should explain the rules. And please tell us what you tried and did not work,

Comment: Are the fields tab- or space-separated?

Comment: add the codes you have it [into your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/666833/edit)

Comment: @pLumo I don't know what you mean with rules. I only want to remove values that are duplicated on the same row. I gave input and output example to make it clear. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @AdminBee Default. (Space separated).

Comment: @αғsнιη I didn't add the code I tried because I deleted it and it didn't work and I felt like I didn't even find the proper approach to it. I realized all what I was doing was just store each column into a multi dimension array with bad conditions around it.

Comment: Aaah duplicated fields in the same row. That information is not in the question...

Comment: @pLumo I will be honest with you, bro. I didn't know how to phrase the question title in fear of being misunderstood. Initially, I was gonna type `How to remove duplicate columns?`. Anyway, I will try to fix it.

Comment: @CodingNoob going forward, please add your attempt to solve the problem yourself to all  questions you ask as then we can help you with not just a solution but feedback on what went wrong in your attempt so you can learn more from our answers. You'll also find more people willing to help you if you try to solve the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        printf "%s", (!seen[$i]++? (i==1?"":FS) $i: "" )
    delete seen; print ""
}' infile
```

Comment: I've come up with `awk '{ delete seen ; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( ! ($i in seen) ) { printf "%s ",$i ; seen[$i]=i ; } ; printf "\n"}'` which is more or less the same.

Comment: @Archemar `print ""` is better than `printf "\n"` because the former uses `ORS` while the latter uses a hard-coded character `\n` that you hope will be the same as `ORS`. Also any time you use an array named `seen` it should idiomatically be used as just `if (seen[str]++)` or similar to distinguish first from subsequent occurrences of `str` it shouldn't be used as `if ( !(str in seen) ) { seen[str] }` or similar as that redundancy of using the array in 2 places isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( !seen[NR,$i]++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", (i>1 ? OFS : ""), $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 3 2
3 2
1
5 2 7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Engr. Ed. I indeed was expecting you to come by. I noticed in your approach you didn't delete the array (unlike αғsнιη's answer). Is deleting the array going to be any better or could it save some memory? Also, what if I want to remove duplicates regardless of the letter case (e.g. `HELLO Hello hello`), how would I do that?

Comment: Deleting the array and using `seen[$i]` instead of `seen[NR,$i]` would save you memory which would only be an issue if your input file was massive, in which case `seen[$i]` with `delete seen` might run faster too, otherwise `seen[NR,$i]` without `delete seen` as I have will probably run faster simply by not calling `delete` once per line. If you want it to be case-independent then just change `seen[NR,$i]` to `seen[NR,tolower($i)]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
{
  split($0,a); $0=""
  for (i=j=1; i in a; i++)
    if (!(index(FS $0 FS,FS a[i] FS)))
      $(j++) = a[i]
}1' file
```

Output:-

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 3
4 3 2
3 2
1
5 2 7
```

---

```
perl -lane 'my %h;
  print join $", grep { !$h{$_}++ } @F;
' file
```

---

Using GNU sed with extended regex mode turned ON `-E`:

```
sed -Ee '
  s/.*/ & /;ta
  :a
    s/( (\S+) (.* )?)\2 /\1/
  ta
  s/ (.*) /\1/
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly like the other answers, but with rebuilding the "current record", printing it by means of that `1` at the very end.

```bsh
awk '
    {
        delete seen
        nf = 0

        for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
            if (!seen[$i]++)
                field[++nf] = $i

        $0 = ""

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
            $i = field[i]
    }; 1' file
```

Again, but getting rid of one loop (making it implicit with a call to `split()`):

```bsh
awk '
    {
        delete seen
        nf = split($0, fields)

        $0 = ""

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
            if (!seen[fields[i]]++)
                $(NF+1) = fields[i]
    }; 1' file
```